# RSpec expect something before expect raise_error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Imagine there's a method that rescues and does some logging.

```
def do_something
  # do stuff
  some_client.call(var1)
rescue StandardError => e
  # log some stuff.
  Rails.logger.error("#{self.class} - Var 1 is #{var1}.") if e.is_a?(MyError)

  raise
end
```

Then in the RSpec, I'd like to

- assert the error is raised.
- it logs the error

```
before do
  allow(Rails.logger).to receive(:error)
  allow(some_client).to receive(:call).and_raise(MyError)
end

it "logs the error" do
  subject

  expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:error).with(/some message with var1/)
end

it "raises MyError" do
  expect { subject }.to raise_error(MyError)
end
```

`expect { subject }.to raise_error(MyError)` part is working as expected, but how should I assert the logging? With the example code above, RSpec will report the error on the raised error without asserting the logging.

Answer (score 6):

Just put them both in the same `it`. Expect that it raises an error and logs it.

```
it "raises MyError and logs it" do
  expect { subject }.to raise_error(MyError)
  expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:error).with(/some message with var1/)
end
```

Alternatively if you really want to check that it logs the error in a separate `it` you'll have to rescue the error. Otherwise your spec will fail (unhandled error)

```
it "logs the error" do
  subject
rescue
ensure
  expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:error).with(/some message with var1/)
end
```

Comment: The hero we don't deserve.